# Spell Checker API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to normalise words entered by users in my application by spell checking words, and these seem options for that:

1. To use an [online API for spell checking](https://www.mashape.com/search?query=spell%20checker).
2. To use a browser based spell checking API, I found that HTML5 defined spellcheck attribute, but this one seems to offer a way to handle events.
3. A JavaScript spell checking library?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one JavaScript library, which may work for you.

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

See, if that helps.